# Meaning of 'meant' in this sentence

Tags: meaning

This is an actor's line from "waiting for forever".

The boy climbs up a big object. and the girls says:

> This was so not meant for heels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think "This object was really not designed to be climbed on by someone wearing high-heeled shoes."

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest you can come to a synonym for "meant" in that sentence is *intended*:

> **intended** |inˈtendid|
>   *adjective* [ attrib. ]
>   planned or meant : *the intended victim escaped*. [NOAD]

Answer (score 2):

Meant as adjective: supposed, expected, required:

> intended Parties are meant to be fun.

"It was not Meant for"  means it was not supossed to happen, An unusual action.